# getpid() returns parent ID

Tags: c, process, signals, fork

i have write the following code as an exercise to understand time signal  , but i get unexpected output , which is give me the parent process ID , when i call getpid() function from the child !

this  a sample from the output :

```
Im the parenet  6355
 I'm , the child 6365 
 Okay , Wait a minute !!! ,  my ip is 6355
```

and this is the code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
void function(int ) ;
void catch_alarm_signal() ; 
void catch_alarm_signal()
{
    printf("Okay , Wait a minute !!! ,  my ip is %d \n " , getpid());
    signal(SIGALRM , catch_alarm_signal);
}
void function(int Read)
{
    signal(SIGALRM , catch_alarm_signal);
    sleep(15) ;
    char string[1] ;
    //read(Read , string , 1 ) ;
    printf("And my input is %s \n" , string) ;
    exit(0);
}
int main()
{
    int fd[2] ;
    //pipe(fd);
    int i   ,pid;
    signal(SIGALRM , catch_alarm_signal);
    for(i =  0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        pid = fork() ; 
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            printf("I'm , the child %d \n" , getpid());
            function(fd[0]);
            i = 10 ;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Im the parenet  %d\n " , getpid());
        }   
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        alarm(1) ; 
        wait();
    }
    //write(fd[1] , "5" , 1);   

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Of course you get the parent pid; you install the signal handler in the parent, and then request an alarm in the parent!

Comment: Also, in future, please post the *actual* code that corresponds to your output.  Also, please make sure to remove all irrelevant stuff from your code (for example, what is with all the `fd` stuff?).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , i think that alarm signal will be set in the parent , and if the time finishes ,  the signal will follow to all childs ! , secondly , what is the effect of install signal handler in both parent and child ? assume that parent will recieve an alarm signal , and it will send an alarm signal , so what is the solution ?

Comment: I'd be happy with actual code that actually *compiles*.

Comment: @WhozCraig , i just change the string in printf() !! , because they are 'bad english' , if you know what i mean , and i forget to recompile it , so the change in what the code print , it will change on the output

Comment: The output of the compiler error-report for the invalid syntax of `int i, ; //pid` and the corresponding unknown identifier `pid` in the rest of `main()` was more what I was referring to.

Comment: @WhozCraig , i will recompile the code ...

Comment: @WhozCraig , i think that there is no problem now.